# How to automate this part of the sql code?

Tags: sql, powerbi, teradata

I help my team do monthly reporting.

For the below case when statement, can anyone kindly show me how to automate this part of the code instead of writing an additional line of the case when statement every time I do reporting? I want to use the code in Power BI to pull data. As you can see week 1 has 8 days, other weeks have 7 days each.

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN DATE BETWEEN '2023-05-24' AND '2023-05-31' THEN 'Week 1'
        WHEN DATE BETWEEN '2023-06-01' AND '2023-06-07' THEN 'Week 2'
        WHEN DATE BETWEEN '2023-06-08' AND '2023-06-14' THEN 'Week 3'
        WHEN DATE BETWEEN '2023-06-15' AND '2023-06-21' THEN 'Week 4'
        WHEN DATE BETWEEN '2023-06-22' AND '2023-06-28' THEN 'Week 5'
        COUNT(ACCOUNT_NUMBER)
        ELSE 'other' 
    END AS Account_open_week
FROM
    acct
```

Comment: What is the logic you use to decide what dates represent `week 1`, `week 2` etc when you have to update this manually? It is "Week 5 is prior full week, week 4 is the full week before that, etc" ?

Comment: There might be a way to create a custom start date with week number, but I'm not familiar with Teradata. As an alternative bandage solution, one could create a calendar table with two columns.... date and your_custom_week_nbr. Then join to it.

Comment: Are you starting from current date and going back 5 "weeks"?  What is  week here?  Btw, that  is not any sort of valid sql.

Comment: Hi JNevill, thanks for your response. The date is determined by my team and I have to update it every week. and reporting period is always Thursday to the following Wednesday except for week 1

Comment: If the number of weeks is fixed (i.e. always 5 or 8 or ...) and it's always based on an offset to the current week (e.g. always 10 weeks up to the previous wednesday) this can be done with some clever calculation.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with:

```
SELECT CONCAT('Week ', WEEK(DATE, 0) - 21)
```

Note that your week start on a Wednesday what is a bit strange so you might need to take this into account and substract first a few days..

the 21 is the amount of weeks already pasted since the 24th of may, I do not know if this is 100% correct

Answer (score 0):

If you can base it on current date, you can derive an offset, and use that to create your week buckets.  Here's an example using the sys_calendar.calendar view.

```
select
c.calendar_date,
row_number() over (order by calendar_date desc) as offset,
case 
    when offset between 29 and 36 then 'week1'
    when offset between 22 and 28 then 'week2'
    when offset between 15 and 21 then 'week3'
    when offset between 8 and 14 then 'week4'
    when offset between 1 and 7 then 'week5'
end as der_week
from
sys_calendar.calendar c
where
calendar_date between current_date - 35 and current_date
order by
calendar_date
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thank you for your comment. week1-5 are not the only weeks I need to specify as there will be week 6, week 7...etc. Using the code you suggested, is the case when statement still needs to be manually added for the on-going weeks?

Comment: That depends on what exactly you mean.  In theory you can just add when statements.  Or you could consider storing it in separate table.